# 8PST switches, do they exist? (not 8SPST DIP Switch)

Tags: switches

I'm looking for a switch that can connect/disconnect 8 signals at a time with one button/lever/slide whatever. Power requirements are very low. I do not want to use analog switches due to interference with my measurements, which are in the nanoamp range.

I would prefer something that is through-hole or surface mount instead of solder lugs. Does such a switch exist?

Comment: How do you feel about relays? Would one switch controlling 8 SPST relays (or 4 DPST relays etc.) work for you?

Comment: Reed relays are hard to beat. Even so, if they're PCB-mounted, you'll have to do outguard-rings around them to quell leakage currents - that requires a buffer amplifier.

Comment: Have you considered a series of rotary switches, interlocked by all being on the same shaft?  Like this: https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/rotary-switches/0327686/

Comment: Jack B  Good thinking, 4 DPDT telecom relays and a switch would probably be much cheaper that an 8PST switch even if one still existed.  Modular switchs like that used to exist but I can't remember the company and they probably didn't survive the digital age.

Comment: Jack B: I would like the power consumed by the switching mechanism to be zero, so purely mechanical is highly preferred.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

*Figure 1. Various "wafer" rotary switches."*

The common forms of these wafer rotary switches have 30° detents and one or more "wipers" contacts which switch between the twelve contacts. The wipers and contacts can be arranged in

- 12-way, 1-pole
- 6-way, 2-pole
- 4-way, 3-pole
- 3-way, 4-pole
- 2-way, 6-pole

Usually a stop ring can be added to restrict the number of switchable positions. Wafers can be stacked if more poles are required.

For your application two 2-way, 6-pole wafers should suffice as you only require eight poles.